# How to add alphabetical column sorting to a table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

Essentially I need to add a little button or something within the headers of the table to be able to sort the data alphabetically by column. I've been having trouble with doing this making use of AngularJS and need some help with it.

This is a snippet showing the table and...

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Ref</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Domain</th>
            <th>Service Owner</th>
            <th>Stage</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ng-repeat-start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProp">
            <td><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
            <td>{{x.b}}</td>
            <td><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
            <td>{{x.d}}</td>
            <td>{{x.e}}</td>
            <td>{{x.f}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="6">
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <p>Test</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a plnkr of the code http://plnkr.co/edit/OkRbR9geeOcCGy2K01jB?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try for a very simple solution:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Status<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'a'">^</a></th>
        <th>Ref<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'b'">^</a></th>
        <th>Service<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'c'">^</a></th>
        <th>Domain<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'd'">^</a></th>
        <th>Service Owner<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'e'">^</a></th>
        <th>Stage<a ng-click="orderProperty = 'f'">^</a></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in projects | orderBy:orderProperty">
            <td><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
            <td>{{x.b}}</td>
            <td>{{x.c}}</td>
            <td>{{x.d}}</td>
            <td>{{x.e}}</td>
            <td>{{x.f}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.orderProperty = "f"; // Sort by "f" by default
    $scope.projects = [...];
});
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/3nxykbhk/

Comment: I tried something very close to that but I see why it didn't work. I used `ng-click` but I didn't attach it to a clickable property, just the `<th>`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I would like to alternate between reversing the sorting on click how would I go about doing that? I've tried various things to no avail.

Comment: The documentation for orderBy seems to have exactly what you're looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy